# How to make a smooth line graph in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a boxplot that shows a change in cl_conc by treatment, which is colored by days and faceted by soil_type (See photo #1) and this line of code:

```
ggplot(leach.conc, aes(x=factor(treatment, level=c('Liquid', 'Solid', 'KCl', 'Control')), y= cl_conc, fill= as.factor(days))) +
  labs(x="Treatment", y="Chloride concentration (mg/L)", fill = "Days") +
  scale_fill_brewer() +
  geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(.~soil_type)
```

I think that this may be better represented with line graphs where days is the x axis, treatments are colored but still facted by soil type (see example photo #2).

However, I cannot get ggplot to create this graph, and I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

I used this code:

```
ggplot(leach.conc, aes(x = days, y = cl_conc, fill = treatment)) +
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(.~soil_type)
```

but am receiving this output (See photo #3). It is not coloring the data the way that it should, and is not a smooth line that I am expecting. Is there a function that I should be using to smooth the data out?

Boxplot I would like to replace:

[image]

What I would like to show:

[image]

Line graph I am receiving:

[image]

Here is my dput for reproducibility

```
leach.conc <- data.frame(
  core = c(
    "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "ML", "ML", "ML", "ML", "MK", "MK",
    "MK", "MK", "MC", "MC", "MC", "MC", "FS", "FS", "FS", "FS", "FL",
    "FL", "FL", "FL", "FK", "FK", "FK", "FK", "FC", "FC", "FC", "FC",
    "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "ML", "ML", "ML", "ML", "MK", "MK", "MK",
    "MK", "MC", "MC", "MC", "MC", "FS", "FS", "FS", "FS", "FL", "FL",
    "FL", "FL", "FK", "FK", "FK", "FK", "FC", "FC", "FC", "FC", "MS",
    "MS", "MS", "MS", "ML", "ML", "ML", "ML", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK",
    "MC", "MC", "MC", "MC", "FS", "FS", "FS", "FS", "FL", "FL", "FL",
    "FL", "FK", "FK", "FK", "FK", "FC", "FC", "FC", "FC", "CS", "CL",
    "CK", "CC", "PS", "PL", "PK", "PC", "CS", "CL", "CK", "CC", "PS",
    "PL", "PK", "PC", "CS", "CL", "CK", "CC", "PS", "PL", "PK", "PC",
    "CS", "CL", "CK", "CC", "PS", "PL", "PK", "PC", "CS", "CL", "CK",
    "CC", "PS", "PL", "PK", "PC", "CS", "CL", "CK", "CC", "PS", "PL",
    "PK", "PC", "CS", "CL", "CK", "CC", "PS", "PL", "PK", "PC", "CS",
    "CL", "CK", "CC", "PS", "PL", "PK", "PC", "CS", "CL", "CK", "CC",
    "PS", "PL", "PK", "PC", "CS", "CK", "CL", "CC", "PS", "PL", "PK",
    "PC", "CS", "CL", "CK", "CC", "PS", "PL", "PK", "PC", "CS", "CL",
    "CK", "CC", "PS", "PL", "PK", "PC"
  ),
  core_id = c(
    "MS1", "MS1", "MS1", "MS1", "ML1", "ML1", "ML1", "ML1", "MK1",
    "MK1", "MK1", "MK1", "MC1", "MC1", "MC1", "MC1", "FS1", "FS1",
    "FS1", "FS1", "FL1", "FL1", "FL1", "FL1", "FK1", "FK1", "FK1",
    "FK1", "FC1", "FC1", "FC1", "FC1", "MS2", "MS2", "MS2", "MS2",
    "ML2", "ML2", "ML2", "ML2", "MK2", "MK2", "MK2", "MK2", "MC2",
    "MC2", "MC2", "MC2", "FS2", "FS2", "FS2", "FS2", "FL2", "FL2",
    "FL2", "FL2", "FK2", "FK2", "FK2", "FK2", "FC2", "FC2", "FC2",
    "FC2", "MS3", "MS3", "MS3", "MS3", "ML3", "ML3", "ML3", "ML3",
    "MK3", "MK3", "MK3", "MK3", "MC3", "MC3", "MC3", "MC3", "FS3",
    "FS3", "FS3", "FS3", "FL3", "FL3", "FL3", "FL3", "FK3", "FK3",
    "FK3", "FK3", "FC3", "FC3", "FC3", "FC3", "CS1", "CL1", "CK1",
    "CC1", "PS1", "PL1", "PK1", "PC1", "CS2", "CL2", "CK2", "CC2",
    "PS2", "PL2", "PK2", "PC2", "CS3", "CL3", "CK3", "CC3", "PS3",
    "PL3", "PK3", "PC3", "CS1", "CL1", "CK1", "CC1", "PS1", "PL1",
    "PK1", "PC1", "CS2", "CL2", "CK2", "CC2", "PS2", "PL2", "PK2",
    "PC2", "CS3", "CL3", "CK3", "CC3", "PS3", "PL3", "PK3", "PC3",
    "CS1", "CL1", "CK1", "CC1", "PS1", "PL1", "PK1", "PC1", "CS2",
    "CL2", "CK2", "CC2", "PS2", "PL2", "PK2", "PC2", "CS3", "CL3",
    "CK3", "CC3", "PS3", "PL3", "PK3", "PC3", "CS1", "CK1", "CL1",
    "CC1", "PS1", "PL1", "PK1", "PC1", "CS2", "CL2", "CK2", "CC2",
    "PS2", "PL2", "PK2", "PC2", "CS3", "CL3", "CK3", "CC3", "PS3",
    "PL3", "PK3", "PC3"
  ),
  soil_type = rep(
    c(
      "WSL", "NCL ", "WSL", "NCL ", "WSL", "NCL ", "ESL", "FAH",
      "ESL", "FAH", "ESL", "FAH", "ESL", "FAH", "ESL", "FAH", "ESL",
      "FAH", "ESL", "FAH", "ESL", "FAH", "ESL", "FAH", "ESL", "FAH",
      "ESL", "FAH", "ESL", "FAH"
    ),
    rep(c(16L, 4L), c(6L, 24L))
  ),
  treatment = c(
    "Tl", "Tl", "Tl", "Tl", "SM", "SM", "SM", "SM", "KCl", "KCl",
    "KCl", "KCl", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Tl",
    "Tl", "Tl", "Tl", "SM", "SM", "SM", "SM", "KCl", "KCl", "KCl",
    "KCl", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Tl", "Tl",
    "Tl", "Tl", "SM", "SM", "SM", "SM", "KCl", "KCl", "KCl", "KCl",
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Tl", "Tl", "Tl",
    "Tl", "SM", "SM", "SM", "SM", "KCl", "KCl", "KCl", "KCl", "Control",
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Tl", "Tl", "Tl", "Tl", "SM",
    "SM", "SM", "SM", "KCl", "KCl", "KCl", "KCl", "Control", "Control",
    "Control", "Control", "Tl", "Tl", "Tl", "Tl", "SM", "SM", "SM",
    "SM", "KCl", "KCl", "KCl", "KCl", "Control", "Control", "Control",
    "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control",
    "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl",
    "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM",
    "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl",
    "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control",
    "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl",
    "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM",
    "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl",
    "Control", "Tl", "KCl", "SM", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control",
    "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl",
    "SM", "KCl", "Control", "Tl", "SM", "KCl", "Control"
  ),
  days = c(
    0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L,
    11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L,
    0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L,
    11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L,
    0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L,
    11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L,
    0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 11L,
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L,
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 18L, 18L, 18L,
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L
  ),
  cl_conc = c(
    3.6, 18.1, 18.1, 17.4, 3.8, 77.1, 81.4, 66.8, 4.6, 19.4, 22.3, 36.9, 4.1, 1.9,
    1.2, 0.6, 18.2, 27.8, 28.3, 28.3, 15, 107.8, 150.3, 94.6, 12.3, 84.8, 53.4,
    51.9, 17.3, 9.1, 4.25, 1.9, 3.4, 19.8, 20.7, 20.5, 2.3, 102, 56.7, 47.4, 2.6,
    33.4, 15.3, 19.9, 2.9, 2, 1.2, 0.8, 8.1, 37.1, 39.8, 34.8, 4.9, 81.9, 67.5,
    56, 5.9, 41.1, 38.3, 30.9, 17.5, 12.4, 6, 3.1, 2.4, 27.8, 27.8, 24.9, 2.6,
    79.7, 65.5, 55.2, 2.1, 13.5, 20.4, 24.7, 2, 1.6, 1.2, 0.7, 8.4, 42.7, 40.5,
    30.1, 10.3, 121.2, 73.6, 38, 9.4, 53, 38.5, 22.3, 6.6, 4.7, 1.9, 0.85, 4.3,
    5.5, 5.6, 7.3, 3.7, 0.9, 2.8, 7.633503186, 5.245095388, 4.9, 6.3, 5.6, 1.4, 5,
    5.6, 1.4, 5.7, 15.80504568, 7.6, 6.5, 2.5, 2, 2.6, 1.6, 46.5, 52.6, 32.9, 2.8,
    45.1, 1.3, 51.2, 2.6, 47.59251129, 68.3, 38.8, 5.4, 34.1, 66.7, 23.51266468,
    0.6, 34.2, 55.7, 23.8, 5, 42.1, 47.9, 44.3, 0.8, 56.23151874, 81.2, 36.1, 1.6,
    36.3, 48.2, 35.6, 1.5, 44.8, 80.9, 34.66600908, 3.1, 33.3, 81.5, 20.2, 0.4,
    40.1, 66.8, 24.5, 3.6, 39, 68.2, 36, 0.303367677, 31.1, 23.2, 75.7, 0.6, 26.2,
    45.3, 21.3, 0.6, 33.76030379, 47.5, 20.5, 1.1, 28.6, 65.9, 18.9, 0.2, 30.2,
    65.5, 23.3, 2.7, 23.9, 64, 24.7, 0.1
  ),
  cl_load = c(
    0.0072, 0.058825, 0.0543, 0.0609, 0.0076, 0.26985, 0.26455, 0.2171, 0.0092,
    0.0582, 0.0669, 0.119925, 0.0082, 0.0057, 0.0036, 0.00195, 0.0364, 0.09035,
    0.0849, 0.0849, 0.03, 0.3773, 0.4509, 0.3311, 0.0246, 0.2756, 0.1602, 0.1557,
    0.0346, 0.03185, 0.010625, 0.006175, 0.0034, 0.06435, 0.07245, 0.07175,
    0.00345, 0.3315, 0.19845, 0.1659, 0.0039, 0.10855, 0.05355, 0.064675,
    0.003625, 0.0065, 0.0039, 0.0026, 0.01215, 0.1113, 0.1393, 0.1044, 0.00735,
    0.266175, 0.185625, 0.168, 0.00885, 0.113025, 0.105325, 0.0927, 0.02625,
    0.0372, 0.018, 0.010075, 0.006, 0.09035, 0.09035, 0.0747, 0.0065, 0.2391,
    0.22925, 0.1656, 0.004725, 0.0405, 0.0663, 0.06175, 0.0055, 0.0048, 0.0036,
    0.0021, 0.0252, 0.1281, 0.131625, 0.097825, 0.0309, 0.3939, 0.2392, 0.114,
    0.0235, 0.17225, 0.125125, 0.0669, 0.0165, 0.015275, 0.006175, 0.0023375,
    0.0043, 0.00825, 0.0042, 0.0073, 0.0037, 0.001575, 0.0014, 0.011450255,
    0.005245095, 0.0049, 0.007875, 0.0042, 0.00175, 0.005, 0.0112, 0.0014,
    0.00285, 0.015805046, 0.0114, 0.008125, 0.00375, 0.0025, 0.00325, 0.0032,
    0.11625, 0.14465, 0.0987, 0.0084, 0.0902, 0.0039, 0.1152, 0.00715,
    0.118981278, 0.2049, 0.1164, 0.0135, 0.093775, 0.2001, 0.064659828, 0.0018,
    0.0855, 0.1671, 0.06545, 0.0125, 0.094725, 0.131725, 0.099675, 0.0024,
    0.177129284, 0.2436, 0.1083, 0.0048, 0.1089, 0.15665, 0.1068, 0.0045, 0.1344,
    0.2427, 0.11266453, 0.010075, 0.0999, 0.2445, 0.0606, 0.0012, 0.1203, 0.2004,
    0.0735, 0.0126, 0.117, 0.2046, 0.117, 0.000985945, 0.0933, 0.0696, 0.2268,
    0.0018, 0.0917, 0.15855, 0.0639, 0.00195, 0.101280911, 0.1425, 0.0615,
    0.003025, 0.0858, 0.214175, 0.0567, 0.00065, 0.1057, 0.212875, 0.075725,
    0.0081, 0.0717, 0.192, 0.0741, 3e-04
  )
)
```

Comment: Try `geom_smooth()` rather than `geom_line()`

Comment: Just a note - From your hand drawn example you are expecting smooth lines but all of your data is clustered over 4 days (so 4 locations on the x axis) - what should the line height represent - the mean of all records on that day? The sum?  One thing that will move you forward is replacing `fill =` with `colour =`.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen thanks for the advice. Yes, the points should be the means for that day for each treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best that can be done with the data at hand:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(leach.conc, aes(x = days, y = cl_conc, colour = treatment)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(soil_type))
```

[image]